# Pre-commit phase using SVN and Bamboo CI server

Tags: svn, continuous-integration, bamboo

There is a need in company to allow the QA team asses the quality of the product before the commit is done.

So, we need the possibility to make a build on the CI server ( Bamboo, in our case) before the new code is committed to the repository.

Local builds are not allowed cause the compilation environment should remain the same.

I know that there is such possibility on Team City CI, but at the moment we are looking for such possibilities on Bamboo.

Thank you for help in advance

**Update**
Other suggestions, like switching from svn to git that will allow such workflow are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're going to have to get complicated and setup a build on a new branch that would be merged in after the QA team blesses it.

This sounds pretty awful.

Comment: Yep, it's really awful solution, especially using svn. Any other ideas ? :)

Answer (score 1):

In Bamboo 4, you can configure a plan to build changes out of an unstable branch, and then add a manual stage that someone in QA could run to merge those changes to the stable branch. More @ https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOO/Using+plan+branches

Unfortunately, I believe the automatic merging is only possible with Git, at the moment.